# Buildroot build System Errors

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, buildroot

I'm trying to build buildroot system for linux kernel application.
It is for academic study , so I want to implement my own file system so I should use virtual machine.

so there is some command that I have pressed :

> `git clone https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot`
>
> `make qemu_x86_64_defconfig`

but when I pressed `make`, I received this error :

> rsync -a --ignore-times --exclude .svn --exclude .git --exclude .hg
> --exclude .bzr --exclude CVS --chmod=u=rwX,go=rX --exclude .empty --exclude '*~' system/skeleton/ /root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/

So this command generate a lot of errors :

```
rsync: [generator] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/dev": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [generator] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/etc": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [generator] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/etc/profile.d": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [generator] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/media": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [generator] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/mnt": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [generator] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/opt": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [generator] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/proc": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [generator] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/root": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [generator] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/run": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [generator] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/sys": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [generator] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/tmp": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [generator] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/usr/bin": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [generator] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/usr/lib": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [generator] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/usr/sbin": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [receiver] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/etc/.group.nsk97w": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [receiver] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/etc/.hosts.yBRyXu": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [receiver] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/etc/.passwd.0Uncqt": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [receiver] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/etc/.profile.0E8enu": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [receiver] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/etc/.protocols.DJb4ew": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [receiver] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/etc/.services.AO2ruv": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [receiver] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/etc/.shadow.QE0FTt": Function not implemented (38)
rsync: [receiver] failed to set permissions on "/root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/etc/profile.d/.umask.sh.IN0rhw": Function not implemented (38)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1333) [sender=3.2.3]
make: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:333 : /root/buildroot/output/build/skeleton-init-common/.stamp_staging_installed] Erreur 23
```

Please, how can I fix that? Because I have not seen something talk about how to avoid it
I don't know how or why this error occur.
I have think that it have forget build requirements, but I don't know how to fix it.

Please, have I done mistake somewhere ??

I'm using kali-Linux `5.9.0-kali5-amd64`, does the problem come from there?

Do you think I'll have any other problems after this one?

Thank you for your insights into this "weird" issue.

Comment: Verify that all required packages are installed for your host system; study **docs/manual/prerequisite.txt** or https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#requirement

Comment: Yes it's already done , ... so i'm trying to unselect some module to see if it will be fine

Comment: i think that it updated kernel and packages that are not compatible , ... Or the extracting linux header is bad , ... i have seen this [link](https://github-com.translate.goog/ladar/sedutil/issues/2?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=fr&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=nui,op,sc) , but doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @ledoux Oh, I had a friend with a similar issue! FAT* partitions don't support some filenames which are valid in Windows. Make sure you follow all your steps inside your Linux partition (Ext4). A recommended folder is `/home/{Username}` where `{username}` is your user name (unless you are root, then its `/root`). `/media` makes me presume you are working and extracting inside an external drive or a windows drive, which isn't recommended. A shortcut to your home directory is `cd ~/`.

Comment: i have done it , but i have another problem , `rsync -a --ignore-times --exclude .svn --exclude .git --exclude .hg --exclude .bzr --exclude CVS --chmod=u=rwX,go=rX --exclude .empty --exclude '*~' system/skeleton/ /root/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc/sysroot/` generate a lot of error

Comment: i have build it as normal users , but nothing , ... knowing that the file system is ext4

Comment: i have tried to reinstall rsync , i hope that something will be fine until the end , but it is working very well for now

Answer (score 1):

After discussion on the Buildroot mailing list, it turns out that the issue was with the rsync version. In particular, it's [Debian bug 994543](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=994543).

Answer (score 0):

I talked about some kinds of problems , [here](https://lore.kernel.org/all/1819f3c3-52db-7e21-8d42-f5c2ae434f33@gmail.com/T/)